# Codeigniter widget plugin resulting in error

Tags: codeigniter, module, widget

I'm trying to setup the Widget plugin by wiredesignz at http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/109584/P20 but I keep getting the error. I am pretty sure I have everything setup as directed in the thread, but I'm getting the following when I try `<?php widget::run("test"); ?>` in my view:

```
class Test extends Widget { function run() { echo "test"; } } 
Fatal error: Class 'Test' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\application\helpers\widget_helper.php on line 52
```

The only thing I can think of that is different about my install is that I'm using Phil Sturgeon's template library.

Here is how I have everything structured:

**/application/helpers/widget_helper.php**

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
/**
 * Widget Plugin 
 * 
 * Install this file as application/plugins/widget_pi.php
 * 
 * @version:     0.21
 * $copyright     Copyright (c) Wiredesignz 2009-09-07
 * 
 * Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
 * of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
 * in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
 * to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
 * copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
 * furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
 * 
 * The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
 * all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
 * 
 * THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
 * IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
 * FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
 * AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
 * LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
 * OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
 * THE SOFTWARE.
 */
class Widget
{
    public $module_path;

    function run($file) {        
        $args = func_get_args();

        $module = '';

        /* is module in filename? */
        if (($pos = strrpos($file, '/')) !== FALSE) {
            $module = substr($file, 0, $pos);
            $file = substr($file, $pos + 1);
        }

        list($path, $file) = Modules::find($file, $module, 'widgets/');

        if ($path === FALSE) {
            $path = APPPATH.'widgets/';
        }

        Modules::load_file($file, $path);

        $file = ucfirst($file);
        $widget = new $file();

        $widget->module_path = $path;

        return call_user_func_array(array($widget, 'run'), array_slice($args, 1));    
    }

    function render($view, $data = array()) {
        extract($data);
        include $this->module_path.'views/'.$view.EXT;
    }

    function load($object) {
        $this->$object = load_class(ucfirst($object));
    }

    function __get($var) {
        global $CI;
        return $CI->$var;
    }
}
```

**/application/widgets/test.php**

```
class Test extends Widget {

    function run() {
        echo "test";
    }

}
```

/application/views/layouts/public.php

```
<?php widget::run("test"); ?>
```

Any idea how I can get this working? Is this just outdated?

I've been searching for a better solution to do Widgets but I can't seem to find any. I just need to be able to control what appears on the site sidebar on a page-by-page basis. Are there any alternative methods?

EDIT: Error's from widget library in comments

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: CI_Lang::$active_lang

Filename: libraries/widgets.php

Line Number: 26

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Page::$sys_lib

Filename: libraries/widgets.php

Line Number: 87

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: libraries/widgets.php

Line Number: 27

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: CI_Lang::$active_lang

Filename: libraries/widgets.php

Line Number: 26

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Page::$sys_lib

Filename: libraries/widgets.php

Line Number: 87

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: libraries/widgets.php

Line Number: 27
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi try my widget library it will work for you, it work with loader

[Widget Library](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/161374/)

Comment: Looks good, got it working but I am getting several Errors outputted. I edited the original post to show the errors I'm getting. Any idea how I can fix it?

Comment: I removed the lines         `$this->_lang = $this->lang->active_lang;
        $this->_domain_id = $this->sys_lib->domain_id;` and it seems to have fixed it, is there going to be any problems removing them?

Comment: Also, when I load the widget helper, it is echoing `load->widget($name); echo $ci->$name->run(); } } ?>` at the top of the page, any idea why?

Comment: yes you can remove these all i have used this library for my project that's why has my project code let me remove that code and upload again.

Comment: i hope you are echo in widget also just return value from there helper will automatically echo it.